# How to show all payment methods? Magento 2

Tags: magento2, payment, shipment

When I choose a delivery method, payment methods are not displayed the first time, you need to click on the delivery method several times only then it will show the payment methods available for this delivery method.
And if the form is not filled at all, then not when it doesn’t show payment methods, how can I fix this? 
There is a module Amasty, Checkout.

Comment: Might be it's cause of third part or custom developed modules. you can disabled that modules first and check. hope it works.